# Site list alphabetic sort is case sensitive

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, sorting

When [sorting the site list by name](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name), the sort is case-sensitive, and lowercase sites appear at the end:

[image]

I don't know where the Russian and Japanese site are supposed to be in that list, but *elementary OS* should be up with the rest of the *E*'s.